Cypher: not matching a pattern
For a model of the type (A)-[LinkedTo]->(B)<-[Knows]-(C) I'm looking how to get back all B's linked to A's, but not knowing C's. Can't use the 'where not exists' construction as this would require C's know B's. Also optional match does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

You can use a couple of path pattern expressions:
MATCH (b:B)
WHERE (:A)-[:LinkedTo]->(b) AND NOT (b)<-[:Knows]-(:C)
RETURN b

A path pattern expression efficiently tests for the existence of at least one relationship matching a specified pattern. And you can also use the NOT operator with a path pattern expression to efficiently test for the non-existence of a pattern.

I got "PatternExpressions are not allowed to introduce new variables: 'A'", which is what I also get when using the 'where not exists' construction. I now understand it has to be (:A) and not (A:A), and similarly [:LinkedTo] and not [R:LinkedTo].  Still struggling a bit further with counts, but will figure it out. Thanks !
